# Using global variable to show value on progress bar

Tags: vb.net, variables, module, progress-bar, vb.net-2010

I am making a game in visual basic 2010 and have almost completed it except for one problem that i have encountered in regards to using global variables. I have set them up in a module as shown below:

```
Module Module1
Public Structure Maths
    Public accuracy As Integer
    Public speed As Integer
    Public vision As Integer
End Structure

Public Mathsprogress As Maths
End Module
```

What i am trying to do with these variables is use them within one form to store values so i can transfer those values to a second form. To do this, i have created nested if statements which should set the value of the variable `mathsprogress.accuracy = x` depending on the value of 'incorrect'.

```
  '''''''''''CONTINUED''''''''''''''''''

 Else : incorrect = incorrect + 1


        If incorrect = 0 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 10
        ElseIf incorrect < 2 And incorrect > 0 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 9
        ElseIf incorrect = 3 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 8
        ElseIf incorrect = 4 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 7
        ElseIf incorrect = 5 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 6
        ElseIf incorrect = 6 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 5
        ElseIf incorrect = 7 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 4
        ElseIf incorrect = 8 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 3
        ElseIf incorrect = 9 Then
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 2
        Else
            Mathsprogress.accuracy = 1
        End If

    End If
```

But for some unknown reason, when i use the variable in the second form which is supposed to show the value of 'mathsprogress.accuracy' in a progressbar, it says that 'the Value of 0 is not valid, it must be between the minimum and maximum' which makes me think that the value stored from the IF statement is not being transferred to this third form. The code in the third form is:

```
 Private Sub pbaccuracy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pbaccuracy.Click
    pbaccuracy.Value = Mathsprogress.accuracy
End Sub
```

I know that the variables are set up correctly because it works when i set mathsprogress.accuracy = 10 within the form load of the first form. My problem may lie in where i have placed the chunk of IF statements, can anyone explain?

Thanks

Comment: Have you possible declared Mathsprogress elsewhere in the scope? Or is there any other code assigning values to accuracy?

Comment: It could also be the order things happen in.  The first block can be reduced to a simple assignment like `Mathsprogress.accuracy = (10 - incorrect) `  ... but 2 incorrects is not accounted for